# Query Plan - Estimated Row Count Very High

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a query that populates a temp table with 1692 rows. I had used a table variable but performance was terrible. Now it is improved but still not ideal.

However, I then need to split the **TaskName** values into separate columns. For this I use APPLY (maybe there is a better way to do this?)

The Execution Plan returns **'Actual Number of Rows'** value of over 100,000. Any idea why this is? There are only **1692** rows in the table!

Query plan is below.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ6_JkKfQ

[image]

**UPDATE:** Tried below CASE query from @Biju jose but does not give desired output.

**Output Required:**

[image]

**Output Returned:**

[image]

Comment: can you case statement for this, also adding an index in the temporary table can benefit it.

Comment: Seems to me like actual number of rows and estimated number of rows are the same. While that is more rows than are in the table, if you self-join to a table multiple times, you multiply the number of rows accessed. This doesn't mean this is a performance problem, though. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am looking for a better more efficient way of querying this table to get the desired output. Tried the below CASE statement as suggested but output incorrect. But yes, I also did not know why it was getting so many rows. Now it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using `CASE` statement, Please test the code before run

```
INSERT INTO #TmpClientOnboardingTable
   SELECT 
    f.FundCode
   ,f.FundName
   ,tr.Period
   ,td.TaskName
   ,td.TaskDetailID
   --,tr.LatestComment
   ,[Tasks].[OverallTaskStatus](tr.TaskDetailID,tr.TagID,f.FundID,tr.Period) as 'OverallStatus'
   ,[Tasks].[LatestComment](tr.TaskDetailID,f.FundID,tr.Period) as 'LatestComment'

   --,[TaskDetailID]
   --,[TagID]
   --,[StatusFlagID]
   --,[ApprovalLevelID]
   --,[ApprovedByID]
   --,[ApprovedDateTime]
   --,[LatestComment]
   --,[CommentDateTime]
   --,[CommentPostedByID]
   FROM [Tasks].[TaskRecord] tr
   INNER JOIN dbo.Fund f
   ON f.FundID = tr.FundID
   INNER JOIN [Tasks].[Tag] t
   ON t.TagID = tr.TagID
   INNER JOIN [Tasks].[TaskDetail] td
   ON td.TaskDetailID = tr.TaskDetailID
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[StatusFlag] s
   ON s.StatusFlagID = tr.StatusFlagID
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[UserDetails] u
   ON u.UserDetailID = tr.ApprovedByID
   WHERE tr.Period = @Period 
   AND t.TagID = 4; -- Client Onboarding View -- ('Cash Reconciliation', 'Non Trade Related')
   --AND tr.ApprovalLevelID = 1 -- analyst
   --ORDER BY f.FundCode  

  --optional if its unique
  --CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CL_idx ON  #TmpClientOnboardingTable (Fundcode) 

    SELECT DISTINCT
  c.FundCode
 ,c.FundName
 ,c.Period
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Client Risk Assessment' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'ClientRiskAssessmentParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Client Risk Assessment' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'ClientRiskAssessment'     
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'AML/KYC' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'AMLKYCParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'AML/KYC' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'AMLKYC'     
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Broker' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'BrokerParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Broker' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'Broker'     
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Checklist' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'ChecklistParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Checklist' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'Checklist'     
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Register of Assets' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'RegisterOfAssetsParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Register of Assets' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'RegisterOfAssets'          
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Expense Budget' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'ExpenseBudgetParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Expense Budget' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'ExpenseBudget'     
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Decisions' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END)  AS 'DecisionsParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Decisions' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'Decisions'
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Onboarding Review' THEN TaskDetailID ELSE NULL END) AS 'OnboardingReviewParentID'
 ,MAX(COALESCE(CASE WHEN TaskName= 'Onboarding Review' THEN OverallStatus ELSE NULL END,'RED')) as 'OnboardingReview'     
FROM #TmpClientOnboardingTable c
GROUP BY c.FundCode
        ,c.FundName
        ,c.Period
```

Also, the estimated number is high because you are joining to the same table for 9 times which bloats the number of rows.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. Is there another solution? Thanks

Comment: @Kevin, can you try max on those columns, I have updated the answer, also can you provide us with some sample data and required output based on that I can enhance my answer.

Comment: that worked. Thank you. However, while performance has improved it is still taking on average 15secs to run

Comment: @Kevin, can you add the new plan which is generated based on my query.

Comment: works well now! Thank you! The scalar function in the SELECT query was causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the table variable is giving horrible performance is because table variables have no statistics. Table variables can be every useful but use them with a small number of records to avoid the performance issue.

The estimated number of rows in the clustered index scan is correct; no problem with that statistic. Aaron is right (of course).

In my experience Outer apply also has a very handy usecase, but it's used far too often (very popular because it is a newer feature ...). Most of the cases I have seen are better off using (left) outer join (and optimal indexes of course). That usually gives a much better performance.